# Programmable handheld/wristworn gps

Tags: gps

I am looking for a small programmable gps unit with a simple LCD display.
I want the gps to work in two modes:

1. Display geographic (degrees north and east) position coordinates.
2. Display position on a paper map e.g A3 that I have georeferenced before hand.

For instance if I were going to Barcelona I would print out:
[Barcelona map](http://techpicturess.com/2016/02/barcelona-map/). Next I would read the position of the corners of the map in Google Earth and I would program the device. Next I would be in Barcelona wondering where I was. I would read F6 off the device, look it up on the map and find that I was near Porto Olimpico.

The device should preferably be small, have an accurate and fast gps, waterproof, have long battery life and be readable in bright sunlight.

Comment: Why do you want to relate this to a paper map? Any tablet with access to mobile data will display a map of your location. Why is it better to use a paper map?

Comment: A paper map is foldable, light, and have infinite battery life. My example was in a city but I think would use this solution mostly in the wild. For instance I like sea kayaking and bring a plastic covered paper map on the deck of the kayak. If I could throw a quick glance at my wrist and read of e.g. F6 I would immediately know where on the map I was.

Comment: Fenix 3, but you'll have to convert long/lat onto your map